# How to change the color by clicking on the descendant blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dynamically generate in the target block a certain number of blocks-descendants and fill them with color by mouse click.
The color changes only in the first block, what is the error?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  squ.appendChild(div);
  div.classList.add("color-me");
  div.style.width = 30 + "px";
  div.style.height = 30 + "px";
  div.style.float = 'left';
}
var color = document.querySelector('div.color-me')

color.onclick = function colorChange() {
  color.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id='squ'></div>
```

Comment: How do you want the dynamically generated `div`s to be placed in the box? Anywhere? In order?

Comment: Nothing about your code works...

Comment: It changes only one because  you only select and change one. Google for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I want the color to change by clicking in all the blocks and not just in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` only returns one element so you set the `onclick` event of only one element.  You would either want to use `document.querySelectorAll` and then iterate over each element to set it's `onclick` attribute or just set it when you create the element.

```js
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 squ.appendChild(div);
 div.classList.add("color-me");
 div.style.width=30+"px";
 div.style.height=30+"px";
 div.style.float = 'left';
 div.onclick = colorMe;
}

function colorMe(obj){
    obj.target.style.backgroundColor='white';
  
}
```

```css
 .square{
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #9acd32;
 margin: 30px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="square" id='squ'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also to move the style for small squares into the CSS.

```js
var squ = document.getElementById('squ');
var div;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add("color-me");
  div.onclick = colorChange;
  squ.appendChild(div);
}

function colorChange() {
  this.style.background = 'white';
}
```

```css
#squ {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}

.color-me {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='squ'></div>
```